# Is it possible to reogarnise my /home like it was before reinstallation?

Tags: partitioning, mount

I had to install again my OS. Contrary to [english documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation), I followed the [french documentation step](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/reinstallation_ubuntu#methode_1_reinstaller_tout_le_systeme_sans_toucher_auhome) called *method to reinstall system without touch /home*. The instructions are clearly *choose the "Something Else"* then when list of existing partitions appears *double click on the system partition you want to replace*, so you set this partition with "/" as mount. Nothing else.

*Sorry but I have got a French version, so I try to translate what I see because I do not always find the English version on internet to use the right words. Thanks for your comprehension*

Now it's messy comparing to what it was.
Before, when I used the file manager, clicking on "other locations", it appeared like this:

1. **Computer**
2. **Volume 2 To**

In **Computer** I had the usual directories like:

- /etc
- /data
- /dev
- /bin
- and so on..
- /home

My issue now is in "other locations" it appears like:

1. **Computer**
2. **Volume 449 Go** <- that's my acient /home on there after reinstallation
3. **Volume 2 To**

And in **Computer** there is still:

- /etc
- /data
- /dev
- /bin
- and so on..
- /home

even */home* as default, but that time it is clearly shrinked space and it encroaches on what was purelly dedicated to system.

How could I correctly, recover the same organisation as before. So it means clearly this in "other locations" again:

1. **Computer**
2. **Volume 2 To**

and keep */home* and */* in separated partitions, in case of I must reinstall again, and want to conserve my files that are in */home* ?

I prefer to ask because I won't make a mistake and lose my data.

Comment: The best way to preserve your data from the widest range of dangers (including mistakes) is by using frequent versioned backups.

Comment: It seems like you are asking how to restore your previous /home that is already on a separate partition. Is that accurate?

Comment: @user535733 yes. Currently my previous */home* with all the files and directories in it are in another partition, I did not think it would turn like this but this is the case. My previous */home* is in *Volume 449 Go* and I would like to recover the space too. Because before, about 500Go was for the */* for softwares,libraries (29Go) and the 449 Go were for */home*. I want it to be considered in the same media. UPDATE the current *Computer* is only 29Go now. That's few for me.

Comment: It seems like you are simply asking how to edit /etc/fstab. That was one step in your original creation of the separate /home. Simply edit /etc/fstab to point the new system to the old /home. Resizing partitions seems a separate question.

Comment: @user535733 maybe, I gonna see it if it corresponds.

Comment: It sounds like when installing using 'something else' (I do it all the time) you forgot or didn't realize you needed to mount the /home partition as well, otherwise it'd create a /home directory on your / partition since it needs one to login with gui.  As user53733 has stated; if you add back the fstab entry for your /home, it'll mount 'over' (or shadow/hide) the /home directory on your / partition (which you could later delete using a 'live' media (or using term if careful; but be sure to delete the correct one!), or just ignore it as you'll not see it in general operation).

Comment: @user535733 Thank you very much, I follow your recommandation, after a good reading of documentation (in French, that's more complete honestly), it did exactly what I expected, and no need to install gparted, or any other software for partioning. That was simple actually, but it needed knowledge. Thank you once again.